# Trouble making my script print None in case there is no result to display

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, request, cheerio

I've created a script in `node` using `request` and `cheerio` to fetch the `title` of different posts and their concerning `links` from a webpage. My script can fetch them in the right way.

The thing is the variables defined within my script `item` and `item_link` may not always have the desired results and in that cases the script will throw any error.

> ***How can I implement `try/except` clause or something similar within my script so that the variables `item` and `item_link` will store `None` or `""` (for some posts) in case there is no result to display?***

I've tried so far (working errorlessly as the `titles` and `links` are always present):

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

const url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping';

request(url, function (error, response, html) {
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    $('.summary').each(function(){
        var item = $(this).find('.question-hyperlink').text();
        var item_link = $(this).find('.question-hyperlink').attr("href");
        console.log({
            item,
            item_link
        });
    });
    }
});
```

If I try like the following (used a wrong selector in `item_link`):

```
request(url, function (error, response, html) {
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    $('.summary').each(function(){
        try{var item = $(this).find('.question-hyperlink').text();}catch(err){item = "";}
        try{var item_link = $(this).find('.question-hyperlin').attr("href");}catch(err){item_link = "";}
        console.log({
            item,
            item_link
        });
    });
    }
});
```

The output I expected `""` but I got `undefined` in `item_link`:

```
{ item: 'Trouble making my script print None in case there is no result to display',
  item_link: undefined }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$('.summary').each((i, summary) => {
  let el = $(summary).find('.question-hyperlink')[0]
  console.log({
    item: el ? $(el).text() : 'None',
    item_link: el ? $(el).attr('href') : 'None'
  });
})
```

You want to avoid try/catch for things like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 $('.summary').each(function(){
    var item = ""; var item_link="";
    try{item = $(this).find('.question-hyperlink').text();}catch(err){item = "";}
    try{item_link = $(this).find('.question-hyperlin').attr("href");}catch(err){item_link = "";}
    console.log({
        item : item || "",
        item_link: item_link || ""
    });
});
```

Comment: If you use `item_link: item_link || ""` then the use of `item_link = "";` within `try{item_link = $(this).find('.question-hyperlin').attr("href");}catch(err){item_link = "";}` is totally meaningless? So, what should be the proper way @Vikash Singh?